# Ctrt + F5 in vs 2008 and .Net 3.5 is not working to run my website application

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I can't run a website application from VS 2008. When I press Ctrl + F5 i got an alert "unable connect to ASP.net Deployment server" (sp.) I'm using windows 2k3 sp2.

Thanks!

Comment: Please paste the correct error message

Comment: You may want to chose internet options in IE, then the advanced tab and uncheck show friendly http error messages.

Comment: You may also want to check the event log.

Comment: i tried, but i can't fix. it don't run !

Comment: Check the connection ports, are you using web services?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a firewall or security suite that may be interfering with it?

If there's no helpful error information, you might need to repair IIS/VS. I've seen that fix similar problems in the past.